# How can I put an <input type="text" in a multiple <select>?

Tags: html, select, text, input

I´m using the code below to get an input textfield next to each option in a multiple select, but what I get is a total mess. The first option is in the multiple select but the rest shows out of the select list.

Does somebody knows how can I make that? I´m sorry I can not post images.

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks.

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <input type="text" name="Audi" value""/>
  <option value="bmv">BMV</option>
  <input type="text" name="BMV" value""/>
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <input type="text" name="honda" value""/>
  <option value="peugueot">Peugueot</option>
  <input type="text" name="peugueot" value""/>
  <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
  <input type="text" name="volkswagen" value""/>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <input type="text" name="opel" value""/>
</select>
```

Comment: you cant put a input box in a select. thats horrible and never going to work

Comment: I thought it would. Something like... @JoshStevens

Comment: Audi [text]    so I can fill te text field with data(amount of cars in this case)

Comment: As Josh said you can't go that way. I guess you need a workaround. Try to get the value of the clicked option and then let the user input something related to the selected value

Comment: you would normally have your select box where you choice your car then below you can input the value of it. That is a good UI this ui would not make sense even if you got it working.. but it wont ever work how your trying. @nessy_ftv

Comment: Give us some more info please... You want for example 3 boxes... What the user will do?

Comment: It sucks I stil can not post images... What the user would do is to select the cars the user wants to buy and input  the amount of cars in each car selected. So maybe the user selects 3 cars(Audi, Opel, BMV) an the user wants 2 Audi, 1 Opel and 3 BMV for example @Gerasimos

Answer (score 0):

Do your drop down list but put a generic textbox afterwards.  On the submit action, get the value of the count and apply it to the selected value.

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="bmv">BMV</option>
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
  <option value="peugueot">Peugueot</option>
  <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Count" value""/>
```

That only allows 1 count per save.  If you want to be able to submit counts for ALL models, use a label and an input for each kind: like so

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Audi
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="audi" value""/>
        </td>     
    </tr>
  <option value="bmv">BMV</option>
    <tr>
        <td>
            BWV
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="bmw" value""/>
        </td>     
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. It comes a bit closer to what I'm trying to get. @MarcJohnston

Comment: If this works for you, denote which one worked and mark it as an answer.  Thanks